# Catch-22 on VPN configuration

Tags: vpn

I just moved an office to another site, and I am running into the following problem:

We have a site in Europe (call it site-E), the old site here (site-A), and the new office (site-N). site-E creates data that is synchronized to an SBS server at site-A every night. This server is also used as a RRAS server for people to dial in, with a dynamic IP address through no-ip.org. All of that works fine.

Site-N has a small network with a permanent IP address, protected by a netgear firewall. I now need to sync the data that comes from site-E also onto a NAS that sits on site-N. So I set up a VPN connection from the server on site-A to the firewall on site-N to bring over the data.

The VPN connection connects fine and I can see the resources on the network at site-N. However, when I do that, the server at site-A gets assigned the permanent IP address at site-N (If I try to connect to the server, I end up with a log in of the firewall). As this server is used for RRAS, that is not possible.

When I uncheck the "Use default gatewayon remote network" option in the VPN connection, I can connect and the server keeps his no-ip assigned address, but I can't see the resources on the site-N, so I can't bring over data. So that doesn't work either.

What I would need is a connection that allows the server on site-A to connect to the NAS on site-N and move the data, but anything else should be unchanged. How do I set that up?

The resources on site-A are on a 192.168.0.x subnet, the resources on site-N are on 192.168.3.x. The firewall (192.168.3.1) sets up VPN connections with a 192.168.1.x Address (DHCP). I tried to add a route with

route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.3.1

but that didn't help.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`route add <destination site network> mask <destination site network mask> <VPN remote IP as seen from the host that makes the VPN call>`

Your initial questions lacks most network prefixes information, and the VPN addressing, so I can only guess what they are.

Comment: Sorry, drookie, I am not sure what you are asking. site-A uses 192.168.0.x (DHCP controlled by SBS2011 Server). Site-A has internet access through a cable with a non-static IP address received from the provider. Site-N uses 192.168.3.x (DHCP controlled by a Netgear firewall). Site-N has a static IP (let's call it 22.22.22.22). I would like to set up a VPN connection between site-A and site-N, that is only used to connect the two sites, but not used for internet traffic (Each site has their own access).

Comment: So, siteA makes a VPN call to the siteN. Last piece of information is the VPN type and, if it's a dial-up VPN, its address space - and what I need to hear from you - is the IP address of the VPN gateway that it assigns to itself. And it better be the dial-up VPN, not the legacy ipsec VPN, because it the latter case the whole stuff becomes more complicated.